# Changing text box ForeColor and BackColor property value has no effect

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Using Winform, I have a textbox whose default value is grey, and I want it to become whitewhen I click it.

So I change the value of the property like this:

```
tb_OutputFileSuffix.ForeColor = SystemColors.ActiveCaptionText;
tb_OutputFileSuffix.BackColor = SystemColors.ActiveCaption;
```

The code is reached, the value is modified properly, but the displayed color remains white. I tried calling the Refresh method without getting more success.

What am I missing ?

Thanks

Comment: Your code works just fine. Is the text seleted? The selectioncolors will usually override the others.

Comment: Note that these system colors are not "white" and "black". They are dynamically configurable by the user. You probably should not be using them as colors for a textbox.

Comment: I tried using System.Drawing.Color instead of SystemColors and it actually worked, thank you. What is weird though, is that when I set my text box color to ActiveCaption ActiveCaption from the property window, it displays white as it should, but using this at run time displays grey.